# GitHub README.md file is not displaying the video

Tags: github, markdown, readme

In Github Readme, I would like to display a video. But it's showing the link only instead of video preview.

You can also find the file here.
[Readme.md](https://github.com/hirenrafaliya/pexels-api-swiftui-mvvm/blob/st-demo/README.md)

```
Video 1 : Not working
  
https://github.com/hirenrafaliya/pexels-api-swiftui-mvvm/raw/st-demo/assets/app-recording.mp4

Video 2 : Working  

https://github.com/hirenrafaliya/pexels-api-swiftui-mvvm/raw/st-demo/assets/244897901-62f541aa-aa8c-43f5-9ead-4b7a2e0d7c2a.mp4
```

[image: Readme.md]

Video 1 : .mp4 & 1.44 MB

Video 2 : .mp4 & 2.47 MB

Both files are in same format & almost similar size.

I've tried another way of embedding a video like below. Which is just showing a default error icon.

```
Video 1 : Not working
  
[![V1](image-link)](https://github.com/hirenrafaliya/pexels-api-swiftui-mvvm/raw/st-demo/assets/app-recording.mp4)

Video 2 : Working  

[![V2](image-link)](https://github.com/hirenrafaliya/pexels-api-swiftui-mvvm/raw/st-demo/assets/244897901-62f541aa-aa8c-43f5-9ead-4b7a2e0d7c2a.mp4)
```

[image]